# Ubuntu 18.04 updates giving me error messages about packages not being upgraded/updated

Tags: 18.04, package-management, updates, python

While running Ubuntu updates, I get error messages saying that some package updates have failed, including python,and that MaxReports is full so no notice is being sent anywhere. I have searched for recommendations but have been mystified by the answers (I am very new to Linux). One suggestion was to run the "sudo reinstall python3" command but that failed to even run.  One place recommended a complete reinstall of Ubuntu, which I am willing to try, but I don't feel confidence in my ability. To do a reinstall do I need a boot disk? Do I need to uninstall first? My computer is a Dell XPS 8300 with two partitions, a Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04.  I am trying to get away from windows7 before it "dies"